# How do I figure out my Windows 10 / Cygwin Proxy settings so I can use curl from CLI?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin

...or is there a way to make curl pick up those settings in Cygwin? I could do this blindfolded probably on Ubuntu. :-/  My objective is to eventually get Sdkman working. We could really use that. Right not I can't even download it without using a GUI browser. That implies I have to solve the download problem before it will even work.

Comment: Alternative idea: ditch Cygwin.  Get curl for native Windows. (Stefan Kanthak's 7.55.1 from [official cURL download page: Win32 section](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) has a pretty small executable file.)  I know, that might not work as well in some scenarios like if you're trying to use alongside other Cygwin software in a shell script, but since I don't know your usage scenario, I'm just tossing this out for possible consideration.  I've been liking it.

Comment: As a Linux guy, I naturally default to ditching Windows. ;-) ...but if I do as you say, I might be able to dump the settings so that I can do it the way that I want to... Hmm...

Comment: not clear the question. Windows proxy settings are usually the one in Internet Explorer proxy option

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that they are set to "automatic" and IDK what that even means. ...so I thought I would find a way to dump or display what they actually are set to.